# StorageFile.CopyAsync doesn't close the file UnauthorizedAccessException UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

i have the following code (C#):

```
StorageFile MyFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(BaseUri, "/SamplePhoto.jpg"));
await MyFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "NewName.jpg");

[...]    

StorageFile temp = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("NewName.jpg");
```

I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException when i try to get the temp file. Maybe the CopyAsync istruction leaves the file open and then I'm not able to read it.

Comment: Why not to try `StorageFile temp = await MyFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "NewName.jpg");`?

Comment: I semplified the code to view if the exception has occurred because the code in between of the first and second row and the third. Even if i write them in sequence the exception still occurrs.

Comment: I've tried the code and there should be no problem with this (unless there is something more in `[...]`). Maybe the problem is with URI, how your BaseUri looks like? I've tried like this: `StorageFile MyFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///test.jpg"));` - no exception.

Comment: I've replaced BaseUri with 
    new Uri("ms-appx:///SamplePhoto.jpg"); 
but the exception still occurs

Comment: Can you share a sample project?

Comment: i've found the problem. I wanted to delete all the file in the LocalFolder and i tryed with the command: ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.DeleteAsync();
but so i deleted the whole folder.